# How to delete rows that are hidden during auto filter

Tags: vba, excel

I hope someone can help with this problem. I am trying to delete two rows after an autofilter delete. this is how the data is displayed on the worksheet:

```
col(A)   Col(B)   Col(C)   Col(D)  Col(E)  Col(F)  Col(G)

head1    head2     head3    head4   head5   head6  head7

data     data      data     data     data   data   data  data  data  data   data

                                      total orders old   data sum
                                      total orders new   data sum
```

I need a way to delete the total orders old and total orders new. the problem is that the range of data varies. the following code is supposed to delete the active cells after the auto filter deletes the row of data. is there a way to delete the hidden rows (total orders old and total orders new) when the auto filter filters the data row?

```
    With Sheet18

    'delete the header for the IMGA range
     Dim find As String: find = Me.CboDelete.value
     Dim rng1 As Range


     Set rng1 = Sheets("Jeanette 2017 Monthly Data Sets").Cells.find(What:=find, After:=Sheets("Jeanette 2017 Monthly Data Sets").Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True)

  If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
     rng1.Offset(-1).EntireRow.Delete
  End If

'delete the IMGA from the Monthly data set

        'Apply the filter
        .Range("A84:I" & .Rows.count).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Me.CboDelete ', Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="="


        With .AutoFilter.Range
            'On Error Resume Next
            Set rng = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.count - 1, 2)
                      .SpecialCells (xlCellTypeVisible)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Not rng Is Nothing Then rng.EntireRow.Delete 'Shift:=xlUp

           End With

'delete the total order and total imc order rows

'.Range("A84:A2000" & .Rows).Activate
Do Until ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).value <> "IMGA" 'And ActiveCell.value <> ""


If ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).value = "" Then
'Rows(ActiveCell.Row & ":" & Rows.count).Delete

ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=4, columnOffset:=0).Activate
'MsgBox "what is the position of the active cell"

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Resize(2, 1).EntireRow.Delete

End If

Loop
Exit Sub
```

Comment: Is this a button on a form control you are using to determine the delete criteria?  Me.CboDelete

Comment: QHarr- yes Me.CboDelete is a combo box. on  a  user form. The challenge is that each range has headers above and below but the auto filter only filters the name in the cboDelete combo box.

Comment: And you can't set up a multiselect to remove the headers instead?

Comment: QHarr--mutiselect wouldn't work in this scenario due to the autofilter being deployed. I was wondering if there was a way to automatically delete the next two rows after the autofilter deletes the filtered rows

Comment: If you have solved your problem please post as an answer rather than edit into question.

Answer (score 0):

The  following code solved my problem.

```
If Not Me.CboDelete.value = "IMGA_UNKNOWN" Then

 i = 2 Do Until Sheets("test sheet").Cells(i, 1) = Empty And Sheets("test sheet").Cells(i, 9) = Empty

If Sheets("test sheet).Cells(i, 1) = Me.CboDelete Then

    j = i

    Do Until Sheets("test sheet").Cells(j, 1) = Empty
    j = j + 1
    Loop
   Sheets("test sheet").Rows(i - 1 & ":" & j + 1).Delete Shift:=xlUp

End If

  End If
```